# Python hdbcli.dbapi Dash App RBKCD give Server not found in Kerberos database

Tags: python, hana, kerberos-delegation

Ubuntu: 22.04 (Kerberos 5 version 1.19.2, which support RBKCD)
Python: 3.9.16
hdbcli : 2.14.24

- Users have account Kerberos REALM A.
- A mid-tier Dash App server, with serviceaccount and principal in REALM A.
- SAP HANA instance is in REALM B.

Cross realm delegation from A to B, via RBKCD (Resource-Based Kerberos Constrained Delegation)
RBKCD has been setup between service account for SAP HANA and service account Dash App.

`$rb = Get-ADGroup -Server B:3268 -Identity "CN=rbkcd_dl_cdp,OU=Security_Groups,DC=a,DC=example,DC=com"`
`Set-ADUser -Server B -Identity HANA-ACCOUNT -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount $rb`

Port 3268, is ldap global catalog.
`rbkcd_dl_cdp` is a group containing service accounts for mid-tier services.

Then connecting

`host = 'hana.b.example.com'`
`port = 31115`
`cnx_hdb = dbapi.connect(address=host, port=port)`

gives:
**Kerberos error. Major: "unspecified [851968]", minor: "Server not found in Kerberos database"**

We have a similar setup, with MS SQL, which works:

`driver = 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'`
`host = 'sql.b.example.com'`
`port = 1433`
`server = f'{host},{port}'`
`SPN = f'MSSQLSvc/sql'`

`conn_pyodbc=f'Driver={driver};Server={server};ServerSPN={SPN};Trusted_Connection=yes;TrustServerCertificate=Yes'`
`cnx_pyodbc = pyodbc.connect(conn_pyodbc, timeout=2)`

This works :)

I am looking for a "`ServerSPN`" setting for dbapi.connect or an environment variable. ?
Or maybe understand if there is some problems with DNS?

Interestingly:
If the "`;ServerSPN={SPN}`" is taken out of the connection string, then the MS SQL give same error as SAP.

If I set `KRB5_CONFIG` to a temp krb5.conf file, then MS SQL complains if I make silly things.
But HANA seems to not to respect this.

As a temporary fix, a TGT can be created via user PW, which do:
`echo pwd | kinit user@A.EXAMPLE.COM`
And then SAP also works, with a TGT on mid-tier service.

We have the SPN in REALM B registered `hdb/hana.b.example.com B\HANA-ACCOUNT`
I am wondering if I should add SPN with port nr? `setspn -U -S hdb/hana.b.example.com:1433 B\HANA-ACCOUNT`

I have looked at DNS: `nslookup hana.b.example.com` and reverse `nslookup IP-FROM-BEFORE`
This seems fine. :)

​After testing with environment variable KRB5_CONFIG=/TEMP/krb5.conf and setting dns_lookup_kdc = false, I can kind of conclude that it looks like hdbcli is directly going to B.EXAMPLE.COM instead of first negotiating with A.EXAMPLE.COM, like MS SQL.
​
​Does hdbcli (2.14.24) support RBKCD?

Comment: ​The following SPN is registered at B domain:
​hdb/hana.b.example.com
which works in a normal TGT setting.
​
​But it seems the driver always add the REALM in RBKDC. 

So it seems solutions is to register SPN
​hdb/hana.b.example.com@B.EXAMPLE.COM